# How can I use Augeas and Puppet to update a single xml file from multiple resources?

Tags: xml, puppet, weblogic11g, augeas

I have a Weblogic config.xml file that is being created by WLST.  It has the following xml on creation :

```
     `<arguments>-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -Dweblogic.TracingEnabled=true</arguments>`
```

I have a number of puppet resources that need to add the following to the *arguments*:

`-Doracle.net.tns_admin=/opt/tns -Ddomain.home=/projects/server -Does.client.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/oesclient -Doracle.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/oesclient -Doracle.security.jps.config=/projects/cluster/config/oeswlssmconfig/cluster/jps-config.xml -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/cacerts -Xverify:none -da -Dcustom.authz.provider=oes -javaagent:/app/wily/Agent.jar -Dcom.wily.introscope.agentProfile=/app/wily/core/config/IntroscopeAgent.profile`

Is there a way to use a union?  That way if multiple resources are defined with the same startup arguments, there would be no duplication.

Or do I need to append or concatenate the two items?

I anticipate having to add more arguments, from other resources, in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the full content of the file, your best bet will be to use concatenation. Either choose the [Puppetlabs](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/concat) or [Onyxpoint](https://github.com/onyxpoint/pupmod-concat) Puppet module for this. My preference would go to Onyxpoint for a clean implantation [using a parent and children concat fragments](https://github.com/onyxpoint/pupmod-concat#chained-builds).

Create a defined resource type using the concat fragment and add new fragments by instantiating new defined resources.